# How to track multiple bitcoin addresses?

Tags: wallet, android

Let's say I have multiple (N) wallets, with N public addresses and N private addresses. Is there a simple way to track the balance (and transactions, but this is not so important) of those wallets? Ideally I would install an android app with the capability of adding public addresses that allows me to see the balance of those addresses.

I do not need to be able to spend from those wallets, just to be able to see the balance. That is, I do not need to import the private addresses, just the public ones.

Answer (score 1):

usually you can use block explorers to display amounts of your different bitcoin addresses. I tend to go to "blockchain.info". As it is cumbersome to cut and paste everytime, I created a small (Linux/MacOS/OpenBSD) shell script to do this for me (https://github.com/pebwindkraft/ccy_values). There are payed APIs and non payed APIs, the latter one having a limit on requests.

Comment: Nice shell script! Would probably solve my needs, but an Android app would make it easier to track on the go. Maybe a good enough reason for me to code my first android app ...

Answer (score 1):

Electrum software (https://electrum.org/) has a watch-only function that can be used to track any public addresses, which should fit your needs.

Also note that Electrum allows you to generate and track many addresses and private keys from one common secret seed, which is a convenient way of managing several addresses.

(I am in no way affiliated to this software)